# Creating a VF page dependent picklist error?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, picklist, dependent-picklist

I am creating a VF page, on that we need to have 13 picklist fields and 13 dependent picklist fiields. We have created 10 picklist fields and 10 dependent picklist field. For creating 11th dependent picklist it's show the error

> Error:Visualforce pages may not display more than 10 dependent
>   picklists together with their controlling fields. This includes any
>   picklists in components or inline pages.

I am using PE, know that the limit is 10 only for dependent picklist using VF page, is their any other way to do this.For designing I am using this VF page. Kindly tell me any links. Thanks in advance, waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you do javascript and some ajax. 
Here's the idea- put an onChange for the controlling field, it checks to see a value, and then dynamically using selectlist within an actionSupport you can load in the picklist values

select list: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm

action support
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm