# Visualforce pages may not display more than 10 dependent picklists together with their controlling fields

Tags: visualforce, picklist, dependent-picklist

I am creating a VF page with standard controller and on that we need to have 12 picklist fields in one page-block and 12 dependent picklist fiields are dependent on other pick list values. i am getting Visualforce pages may not display more than 10 dependent picklists together with their controlling fields error. Is it possible to display all this fields in one page with validations?

Answer (score 0):

As it's salesforce Idea (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000K3Z9), you should try some custom approach as explained here:

[Creating a VF page dependent picklist error?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12018/creating-a-vf-page-dependent-picklist-error)

https://www.sundoginteractive.com/blog/displaying-dependent-picklist-fields-on-a-visualforce-page